# Is it possible to create a global variable in Opa?

Tags: opa

In MLState's new programming language Opa, is it possible to create a global variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Opa is a functional language so there are no global variables in the language. However, one can achieve a similar behavior with `Mutable`. At top-level one declares the value with:

```
global_var = Mutable.make(initial_value)
```

where `initial_value` is the initial value for the variable (of some type `t`). Then one can retrieve the value with:

```
global_var.get()
```

and set it with:

```
global_var.set(new_value)
```

More information in the [Opa API overview](http://opalang.org/resources/doc/index.html#mutable.opa.html/!/value_stdlib.core.Mutable).

Note however, that this mechanism should be used only in special situations; the primary device of encapsulating state in Opa are its distributed sessions (see the [Opa manual](http://opalang.org/resources/book/index.html) for more on that subject).

Comment: Note that, for the usual value restriction issues, your global mutable variable cannot be polymorphic.